# DocuSign OAuth Flow

Tags: oauth, docusignapi

I am implementing DocuSign's OAuth flow by following [OAuth2 Authentication Support in DocuSign REST API](http://app.esign.docusign.com/e/er?utm_campaign=DevCenter%20Nurture%20Campaign%20-%20Key%20Information%20-%20Email%201&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Eloqua&s=566810826&lid=345&elq=3b564e3b7be249d3bc999dfc1fad5508)

According to the documentation, in order to carry out the ***OAuth Token Request*** the client application should show a UI to prompt the user for email/password and is responsible to keep the information confidential and not store it locally.

I would like to know if DocuSign supports OAuth in the manner where the client application does not take hold of the user's email and password and is just concerned with the **authentication token** of the user.

Answer (score 4):

The [DocuSign Developer Center](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center) has some info on the OAuth process on their SOBO (Send-On-Behalf-Of) feature page.  Check out Explore -> Features -> SOBO.

It's pretty easy to request an access token, just make the following call:

**URL**

```
https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/oauth2/token
```

**METHOD**

```
POST
```

**BODY**

```
grant_type=password&client_id={IntegratorKey}&username={email}&password={password}&scope=api
```

For the body make sure you replace `IntegratorKey`, `email`, and `password` with your credentials.

---

A successful call will generate the following response:

```
{
    "access_token": "<access token for user>",
    "scope": "api",
    "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

And finally, you can then use that access token in subsequent api calls using the `Authorization: bearer` header like so:

```
Authorization: bearer <access_token>
```

One important thing to remember is that you are only allowed **10** OAuth tokens in your account (which can be seen on the Preferences -> Connected Apps screen in the DocuSign Console).  If you have 10 and request a new token the call will fail, you'll need to revoke an existing one in that case if you want to create a new one.

Comment: Why should we need to play with user's password. Docusign OAuth shold take care of it by just providing us the access token

Comment: You need credentials to generate the access token the first time.  Once generated you only need to supply the access token and you don't need the password anymore.  Have you tried my solution to see if it works?

Comment: Yes I have generated the access token using the credentials but my point is the purpose of OAUTH is not fulfilled here. Client Application should have no concern with the user's email and password. Docusign says don't store the password locally! What If any client develops an application that stores the users' passwords and create security threats for docusign users?

Comment: How would I do this in Fiddler? I can do it on the DocuSign developer center, but I'm having trouble replicating that in Fiddler. No matter what I put in the request body, I get an 'invalid_scope' error. I've tried formatting the body section (above) as a URL parameter style and JSON. I've also tried it in the URL.

Comment: @DanielPrzybylski - did you ever figure this out? I'm getting the same scope error every time invalid_scope scope must be API

Comment: Does this type of authentication (grant_type=password) still work with DocuSign?

Answer (score 1):

According to the DocuSign documentation, it supports two grants: (1) the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant and (1) the SAML2 Grant, which is an extension to the base OAuth2 spec.  Neither of these grants issue an authentication token.  In the first grant, the resource owner must share his credentials with the client application.  In the second grant, the resource owner approves access by the client application in advance.  The client app generates a SAML assertion which is validated by the authorization server and (if the assertion is valid) is issued an access token.

The authentication token is used only by the Authentication Code Grant which, according to the DocuSign documentation, is not supported.

Comment: By **authentication token** I mean **access token** only. Can you share a link that can describe SAML2 Grant in DocuSign.

Comment: @Asma I just posted an answer for you...  --Ergin